# Python: How to plot dots for a sort of connect-the-dots game?

Tags: python, user-interface

I'm in the beginning stages of creating a glorified connect-the-dots game in Python, but I am not sure how to plot my dots for this. Specifically, I want my program to be of a map and you can click locations (these are the dots) and draw lines between them. As a side note, I'd also like to be able to hover over these dots to display some information about the locations.

Due to the nature of this, I'd like the dots to be plotted in very specific spots on the map image. I'm not sure how exactly to begin this.

Would it be possible to draw it all out in a .jpg or .png file and have the program locate it itself (the dots would be identified by color) and give them clicking functionality? Or is it best to plot them out in the program itself and perhaps overlay the buttons over an image? I don't even know where to begin with this. One thought I had was that I could use graphs for this with nodes and edges- which would simplify the drawing of lines, but I'm not sure if there is any libraries available to allow for specific location placement of the nodes.

Comment: Take a look at Pygame. You need something to actually draw with in python before you can start making anything.

Comment: you can draw on `Canvas` in `Tkinter`, or `Surface` in `Pygame`. Every GUI framework (`Tkinter`, `PyQt`, `wxPython`) has some function to draw.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered pygame? http://pygame.org

I've found it helpful for drawing very simple graphics before. Plus, I guess what you're describing is in fact a game.

Answer (score 0):

I have some good experience with Python and SVG. Something like plot.ly might work for you https://plot.ly/python/